# How to avoid defensive if conditions in python?

Tags: python, defensive-programming

I am writing a code which tries to dig deep into the input object and find out a value lying inside that object. Here is a sample code:

```
def GetThatValue(inObj):
    if inObj:
       level1 = inObj.GetBelowObject()
       if level1:
           level2 = level1.GetBelowObject()
           if level2:
               level3 = level2.GetBelowObject()
               if level3:
                  return level3.GetBelowObject()
    return None
```

There are many situations where I end up with these "slanted if conditions".
How can I avoid this? This looks dirty and also it is kind of defensive programming.

Comment: `if` is not a looping statement :)

Comment: Can't you ask the level 1 object to get the data for you?

Comment: Your previous edit changes the question drastically and that would make most of the answers obsolete. So, I had to rollback your changes.

Comment: Please post a separate question instead of changing the question radically.

Comment: Yeah...I am sorry for that...I am quite new to asking questions here and I did not expect those quick replies :).

Comment: @user1564890 Expect the unexpected :) BTW, check user2357112's answer. That might be what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try:
    return monkey.TypeWriter().Manufacturer().Shareholders().EthnicDistribution()
except AttributeError:
    return None
```

Try to get the thing. If it doesn't work, you know one of the levels was missing. This works particularly nicely if those `GetBelowObject` calls aren't actually all the same method.

Comment: I would accept this as answer, because flat is better than nested !

Answer (score 9):

Using `for` loop:

```
def GetThatValue(inObj):
    for i in range(4):
        if not inObj:
            break # OR return None
        inObj = inObj.GetBelowObject()
    return inObj
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid deeply nested if statements. Check the exceptional case, and return earlier.

For example, following nested `if`s:

```
if a:
    if b:
        return c
return d
```

can be transformed to flattened `if`s:

```
if not a:
    return d
if not b:
    return d
return c
```

Comment: To add to this, if the method you're calling on each level differs, you can just use return (if not x: return none), thus avoiding unnecessarily deep nesting.

Comment: @user1564890, If you want to avoid deeply nested `if` statement, suggestion of Spikes is a good alternative: Check exceptional condition, and return earlier. (This will make your `if` statements flattened.  See http://ideone.com/oBuszQ